# How to import data from CSV file to LDAP directory and keeping them up to date

Tags: ldap, openldap, csv

lets say I have CSV file in format

```
userID;login;firstName;lastName;validUntil
```

Is here any easy way how to import data from this CSV to LDAP directory and how keeping LDAP up to date based on CSV (this CSV is periodically filled from MySQL database by script)?

I think some script will be necessary, but I guess there have to be some app or something, but I didn't find anything. Thanks all for your replies.

Comment: *but I didn't find anything* - unconvincing sentence is unconvincing. LDAP goes back 25 years and CSVs go back 45 years. People have done this before, lots. Google for `ldap import csv` the top result is not just importing from CSV to LDAP, but a tool for doing that including synchronising from MySQL to OpenLDAP. ( https://lsc-project.org/start )

Comment: Thanks for reply, but  now I'm stuck at the beginning of the tutorial, I can't start the HSQLDB server, reinstall didn't help, also in logs is anything what could be helpful. After I put command `hsqldb --start` everything seems ok, but if I try  `hsqldb --status`, I get only `HSQLDB Server is not running` Has anybody experiences with this? I'm using CentOS 7, kernel 3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64